# How to show the selected options static from db + angular js

Tags: php, angularjs

```
<select name="gender" ng-model="list.gender" data-select-id="bc813756-82d5-45d7-932c-ab9afd0a08da" class="initialized">
    <option value="" disabled="">Gender</option>
    <option ng-selected="list.gender == 'Male'" value="Male" >Male</option>
    <option ng-selected="list.gender == 'Female'" value="Female" >Female</option>                 
</select>
```

Suppose I am getting the `"Male"` value from DB, how to show selected option?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, like you only have two options available for the genre (Male or Female) can use true or false:

```js
var app = angular.module('GenreApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  // This would be the value get from your DB
  var genreGetFromDB = 'female';
  
  // Here you validate the value of the genre
  if (genreGetFromDB != 'male') {
    $scope.genre = false;
  } else {
    $scope.genre = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="GenreApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select aria-label="ngSelected demo">
      <option>Female</option>
      <option ng-selected="genre">Male</option>
    </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

Keep Rocking!

Comment: Please provide more information to understand "why don't working"

Answer (score 0):

We should not use `ng-model` and `ng-selected` together. This is what the `AngularJS` docs says:

> **Note:** `ngSelected` does not interact with the `select` and `ngModel` directives, it only sets the `selected` attribute on the element. If you are using `ngModel` on the select, you should not use `ngSelected` on the options, as `ngModel` will set the select value and selected options.

So, remove the `ng-selected` directive from your options, and set `list.gender` in the controller to the value pulled from the DB.

```
app.controller('someController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    // .... some code ...
    $scope.list = { gender: 'Male' }; // set this to the value from DB

    // .... some code ...
}]);
```

The HTML

```
<select name="gender" ng-model="list.gender" class="initialized">
    <option value="" disabled="">Gender</option>
    <option value="Male" >Male</option>
    <option value="Female" >Female</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps